# use QGridLayout::addWidget with mutythread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qwidget

Since creating widgets takes a lot of time, I try to create widgets in different threads and add them to the main layout, but that fails. When creating widgets and then adding them sequentially, the program works normally. Notifications I received: "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread"
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it.

Qt GUI classes including `QWidget` must be used only from the main thread.
Quoting [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy):

> Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and
>   all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the
>   main thread. As noted earlier, QCoreApplication::exec() must also be
>   called from that thread.

This is enforced in Qt code by a `Q_ASSERT_X` when you construct a `QWidget`:

```
Q_ASSERT_X(q->thread() == qApp->thread(), "QWidget",
    "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread.");
```

So, even if you would find some work around to make it work, you would not have any guarantee that your code will work in a reproducible way and that any Qt update will not break your code.

Regarding your specific problem, creating widgets should not be time consuming. I can think of 2 reasons why it would be time consuming:

- Your widgets are doing heavy computation when you create them. Then you shoul put the computation, and only the computation, in another thread.
- You are creating a lot of widgets in one shot. The you can deffer the creation using the event loop. Basically, you create some widgets then post an event or set a timer that will create some more widget, etc. until you meet some stop conditions.

Comment: My problem is computation. I fixed it that way, but it did not look good at all. I still want to remain consistent, computed in the data contained. Thanks for the help.